How to remove scam sites from the actual LIST on Notifications?
Here's a typical scam site where I must have accidentally clicked yes on the notifications scam panel:
It's easy to click "off", but how do you literally remove the items from that list?



Ah, actually I figured this one out. It may help someone.
Open Safari itself, tap command-comma, and:

Then quit/start System Settings (no need to restart the Mac) and you're good.

Nice work documenting this. Thanks!

Thanks. What a hassle right? :/   It's incredible there's no way yet to report scam sites like that (as one can "report" on phone or sms messages)
